# Why is the loop skipping first line entry?

Tags: java, loops

This is the code :

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of lines : ");
    int a = s.nextInt();
    String[] array = new String[a];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter line " + i + " : ");
        array[i] = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
   }
```

After first Run ( If a is set to 4 ) :

Enter the number of lines : 4

Enter line 0 :

Enter line 1 : test1

Enter line 2 : test2

Enter line 3 : test3

it skiped Line 0 by itself.. why ?

Comment: Use `nextLine()` after `nextInt()` to consume the '\n'

Comment: @ZouZou It worked :) , can you give further explanation on this ?

EDIT : Never mind i read the other problem's explanation and i got it :) Thanks !

Comment: This is one of the most frequently asked questions on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**this cause of unread `\n` in first line** add `nextLine()` before for loop
assume this input for your program

```
4\n
test1\n
test2\n
test3\n
test4\n
```

in line `int a = s.nextInt();` you read an Integer from input and `a` equals `4` but `\n` still exists in input, readable input change to this

```
\n
test1\n
test2\n
test3\n
test4\n
```

after that first time you want to read a line `Scanner` moving forward in input until reach a `\n` character, and in your input `\n` is first character in input so `Scanner` read empty line, readable input change to this

```
test1\n
test2\n
test3\n
test4\n
```

next `readLine` returns `test1` and change input to this

```
test2\n
test3\n
test4\n
```